# compressed sparse column to row conversion

Tags: fortran, openmp

i was trying to convert a compressed sparse column format into compressed sparse row format using fortran. here's what i have so far:

```
program test
implicit none

real*4,dimension(19)::csc_data=(/10.,3.,3.,9.,7.,8.,4.,8.,8.,7.,7.,9.,-2.,5.,9.,2.,3.,13.,-1./)
integer*4,dimension(19)::csc_index=(/1,2,4,2,3,5,6,3,4,3,4,5,1,4,5,6,2,5,6/)
integer*4,dimension(7)::csc_pointer=(/1,4,8,10,13,17,20/)

integer*4,dimension(7)::csr_pointer
integer*4,dimension(19)::csr_index
real*4,dimension(19)::csr_data

integer*4::global_counter,counter,i
integer*4::num_nonzero,num_cols,num_rows
integer*4::s1,s2,c,r

num_nonzero=19
num_rows=6
num_cols=6


csr_pointer(1)=1
global_counter=1

do i=1,num_rows
 counter=0
 do c=1,num_cols
  s1=csc_pointer(c)
  s2=csc_pointer(c+1)-1
  do r=s1,s2
   if(csc_index(r).eq.i) then
    counter=counter+1
    csr_data(global_counter)=csc_data(r)
    csr_index(global_counter)=c
    global_counter=global_counter+1
   end if
  end do
 end do
 csr_pointer(i+1)=csr_pointer(i)+counter
end do     

end program test
```

Could anyone show more efficient approach? I would really appreciate if you could also show it with OpenMP parallelization. Thanks.

Comment: How can you change a 1D array from column-major to row-major?

Comment: @KyleKanos The OP is talking about sparse matrix conversion between formats, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR_or_CRS.29.

Comment: If your code works, but is not as efficient as you would like it, this question is more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @IRO-bot: I see now. I do not usually work with sparse matrices, so my knowledge of it is low.

Comment: @IRO-bot How can I get it to codereview? Thanks.

Comment: Just follow the link above, sign up, then post the question there.

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot comment on the correctness of the algorithm, I can make a few points on the code itself

- `csc_data` is defined as `real*4` while `csr_data` is defined as `integer*4`
- `csc_pointer` is defined as `integer*4` while `csr_pointer` is defined as `real*4`
- If you output the data, aside form the integer/real difference, the data is the same, something I would not expect for converting the matrix
- `csr_index` has an index of `global_i` which should be `global_counter`

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I changed the example, but actually I am planning to run it on a more larger cases...  Thanks.